# Trigger.io native module issue finding resource bundle on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle, native, trigger.io

I'm working on a native trigger.io module specific to iOS, and I've run into an issue trying to load image assets into the module.

I'm using Xcode v5.0.2 starting from the recommended starter ForgeModule code.

In particular, I've followed the native module instructions to a T and have verified that the ForgeModuleResources target is producing a bundle named "media_capture.bundle" any attempt to find the bundle from within the ForgeModule fails.  The only other example I could find of using a resources bundle within a native module was buried in the trigger.io-tabs module, and I've been unable to figure out what could be different between the two.

Here's the snipped I'm using from within my ForgeModule to try and located the resources bundle:

```
    //NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] builtInPlugInsPath]
    //                        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"media_capture.bundle"];
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"media_capture" ofType:@"bundle"];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
```

except bundlePath always ends up nil meaning that there's some issue finding the media_capture.bundle.

Any help or possible pointers here would be really appreciated, as I've been banging my head against this rather trivial issue for some time now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resource bundles should be placed in `module/ios/bundles`, which are then picked up by Trigger.io

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/including_resources.html

> 3rd party bundles can be included by placing the bundles in `module/ios/bundles`. An inspector project update will then be required to include them in the inspector for development
>
> If you have resources such as images that you want to include in your module, you must create your own bundle. The inspector project includes a ForgeModuleResources target which can be used to help with this: